# Error de conexion por usar MariaDB

Tags: php, mariadb

¿Al intentar conectar a mi bd me sale este mensaje? ¿como podría buscar la forma correcta para conectar con MariaDB?

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET_NAMES utf8' at line 1
```

Yo tengo la siguiente clase constructor para crear la conexion:

```
 class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct(
          'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST .
          ';dbname=' . DB_NAME,
          DB_USER,
          DB_PASS,
          array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET_NAMES ' . DB_CHAR
          ));
    }
}
```

Comment: el error no es por usar MariaDB si no por que estas concatenando mal, podrías editar y mostrar el código completo de la clase donde tienes ese constructor?

Comment: Acabo de actualizarlo. Mira por favor el texto inicial.

Comment: Acabo de revisar todo y cambiando esto:
'mysql:host= ' . DB_HOST . (un espacio más después de la comilla)
Deja de dar el error descrito. Lo malo es que ahora me da este otro error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. El caso es que el host lo tengo bien escrito ya que es localhos. ¿Alguna idea de que puede estar fallando?

Comment: Corrijo mi anterior comentario: al añadir el espacio despues de mysq:host= no hice otra cosa que generar otro error anterior al que mostré por primera vez. Por lo tanto es el primer error que mostré el que nos interesa y... sigo sin ver donde falla algún error de concatenación como me decías. ¿has podido ver algo?

Comment: prueba `"SET_NAMES '" . DB_CHAR. "'; "`

Comment: Encontré el error. Es "SET NAMES" (sin el guión bajo):
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES ' . DB_CHAR